# Are there any difference between gravitational potential of different types of black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

There are four possible types of black holes that could exist in the theory of gravitation (called general relativity).

Are there any difference between the value of gravitational potential of these four possible types of black holes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only static spacetimes are derivable from a potential. Spacetimes for rotating black holes aren't static, so they can't be derived from a potential. The spacetimes for nonrotating black holes are static, so they can be derived from potentials. Since the spacetimes are different for black holes with different amounts of charge, it follows that the corresponding potentials are different.